# Facing some complication in my for loop statement?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am using python 3.

```
for i in range(len(basic_elements)):
    value_list = [basic_elements[i], x_count[i]]
```

`basic_element` is a list of words, and `x_count` is a list of number. 
I want `value_list` to give me all the 50 elements in both lists together in `value_list`.
But i kept on getting only the last element.
I don't understand?!

Comment: Then you need to build a list with `.append`. Here you are just replacing `value_list` with a new, two-element list each time.

Comment: But basically, this can be achieved using `value_list = list(zip(basic_elements, x_count))`

Comment: use zip to merge the two list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-can-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the list assigment inside the loop re-initializes the list each time the loop is executed.  I'm not entirely sure what you want your output list to look like, but something long the lines of

```
values_list = []
for i in range(len(basic_elements)):
    value_list.append((basic_elements[i], x_count[i]))
```

should create a list of basic_elements[i], x_count[i] tuples.

Comment: There's no list comprehension in his code.

Comment: ...[basic_elements[i], x_count[i]] is a list comprehension

Comment: or looks like an attempt at one anyway

Comment: I thought a list comprehension is something like `[x**2 for x in other_list]`

Comment: `[[basic_elements[i], x_count[i]]` is simply a list literal.

Comment: my bad, I stand corrected I was thinking too deep, you're just assigning a new list every loop over your old list.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped!!!